# how remove duplicate entries in music list (after reset)?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, music, music-player

How remove duplicate entries in music library (music player). i have factory restore (reset) still double entries of songs list, albums.

I am using android-2.2 Foryo (Samsung Galaxy 551 - GT-5510).

duplicate entries not working... :(

Comment: I got the solution myself. just format SD Card. note:don't take backup of android system file. :)

Comment: Ankur, you could place your solution as answer. This way your question does no longer appear to be "unanswered", and other affected users have it easier to recognize this in lists.

Answer (score 1):

I got solution
Backup your data (note : dont take android data on sd card)

--- Or ---

Or remove your android data folder on SD card

Comment: Accept your own answer as Answer so that this question can be marked "Answered".